# How to get a shared taxi in Morocco?

Tags: public-transport, morocco, shared-taxis

I have been in Morocco recently. I read in many places taxis can be shared. There are grand taxis (sort of vans) and small taxis (normal cars). Grand taxis can be shared. Actually small ones as well although less common.

However, when I approach a grand taxi driver they always tell me such thing does not exist. There are no shared taxis.

Actually, shared taxis exist because I have experienced it. I was invited to join one of these taxis once, while waiting for a bus. Night was falling, and I was clearly confused with a local as they spoke to me in Arabic.

Having this said, I would like to ask what is the protocol to use these shared taxis?
Are there specific places to pick them? Specific routes? What is the right approach? What should I ask for?
If these exist, how can I find the places and routes?

Comment: The shared taxis usually wait in a group, and each driver calls out their destination, which will be another town. When the taxi is full, they leave. The Merc saloon cars (sedans) take 6 passengers: 4 across the back and 2 in the front. The guys crammed in the back sit kipper-fashion, each with one shoulder forward, and by mutual consent they all flip the other way. I recommend you buy both the front seats for comfort. Also, in Morocco French is more useful than English.

Comment: Are there "known places" to get these taxis? If so, is there a  way to find them online or is this informal information that circulates on local comunities?

Comment: I would think any local person would tell you. Or the hotel concierge. Or your Rough Guide etc. They are not going to be a secret, because they have to tout for business.